# My praying mantis has stopped eating

Tags: feeding

I'm a bit worried for my pet Asian praying mantis. He won't eat, just backs away from the crickets.

The problem is that he has gone about a month now with no sign of molting or interest in food. What should I do?

Comment: Does the answer to this question solve yours Lucas? https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/16475/7526