# My mantis won't eat

Tags: insects

I've had my mantis for 4 days now it hasn't eaten in those 4 days, last night and today it's started hanging on the top of it's terrarium and it hasn't been moving much. Is it dying or molting or something else?

Comment: Possibly related: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/16473/my-praying-mantis-pet-is-not-eating-and-has-2-black-lines-on-its-abdomen